# What Are Some of the Component Libraries For Styling C# Windows Form Applications?

Tags: c#, windows, libraries, styling

I am fairly new to C# from developing in Java for about 5 years.  Most of my experience is web and server-side so I am trying to get my head around Windows development.  Currently, I am re-writing an application that was using the Krypton Toolkit by Component Factory to style the application.  I have stripped Krypton out of the project and am now trying to learn more about and decide on a Component Library to use for styling the application.  What are some of the better libraries out there for styling C# apps?  Thanks in advance and sorry if this is already published somewhere.  When I searched, I couldn't find anything.

Comment: To be honest, from a usability perspective, it's better to provide a UI that is consistent with the parent operating system, it leaves the user with a familiar set of controls to get accommodated with. Try not to dress up your UI with artefacts that would confuse the user.

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic at SE sites, http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 0):

There are many component libraries for example [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx), [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/), [ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioWinForms/) and so on...It depends on how much money you want to spend and what funcionality you expect.
But I have question why is Krypton tool kit is not good for you? Iam currently using Krypton tools + [Angel](http://www.advancedcomputing.ch) extended renderer toolkit and Iam quite happy.

Comment: My employer wanted me to get rid of Krypton and I think it was a mistake now that I have discovered how much work is involved to create better looking components.